# Are files without extension dangerous?

Tags: windows-10, filesystems, zip, malware

I recently run a test with Bitdefender and there were several encrypted files that it could not check.

All of them in were in `APO.zip` files which were contained in another Zip files.

Some of them were in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\rtkhdasetting.zip` and one in `C:\Program Files\Realtek\Audio\HDA\rtkhdasetting\103C82BA` folder.

I don’t know what to do with these neither how to open them.

Comment: Technically, an application in windows can run ANY BINARY with our without an extension using the CreateProcess() win32 function.  Windows itself will only technically execute .COM and .EXE files.  If you look at your `PATHEXT` environment variable, you will find other file types that windows is willing to host through known registry associations.  For instance, .BAT files have no binary code but windows will run them with cmd.exe.  Defender has your back and I don't know why you would go seeking to open random stuff defender told you might be a problem.

Comment: Also, if a zip is password protected or corrupt, defender can't look in it and might give you a warning.

Comment: The zip isn´t password protected. The Bitdefender said it could not check those files against viruses because they were encrypded .txt files, inside those files without extension, which I am not even able to open. Perhaps I don´t sound too compllicated. English is not my native langiage.

Comment: *Hopefully I don´t sound too complicated. ...

Comment: Your English is just fine :)  An encrypted text file is not a text file.  If you are worried about those files, move them somewhere else and see what happens.  Probably nothing.

Comment: Nothing obesrvable happens but I am still not able to check them.